# How to allow function to work with integers or floats?

Tags: rust

I [found a function to compute a mean](https://github.com/boxtown/statrs/blob/master/src/statistics/iter_statistics.rs#L58) and have been playing with it. The code snippet below runs, but if the data inside the input changes from a float to an int an error occurs. How do I get this to work with floats and integers?

```
use std::borrow::Borrow;

fn mean(arr: &mut [f64]) -> f64 {
    let mut i = 0.0;
    let mut mean = 0.0;
    for num in arr {
        i += 1.0;
        mean += (num.borrow() - mean) / i;
    }
    mean
}

fn main() {
    let val = mean(&mut vec![4.0, 5.0, 3.0, 2.0]);
    println!("The mean is {}", val);
}
```

Comment: When you say "work with integers" what should the return type be: an integer, or a floating point?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Judging by the chosen algorithm, I would say the OP would like something that always returns `f64`, but that also accepts integer inputs.

Comment: See also `num` crate which I think is underused. It defines `zero` and `one` traits that can be used for functions such as `sum` and `product` for example

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The code in the question doesn't compile because `f64` does not have a `borrow()` method. Also, the slice it accepts doesn't need to be mutable since we are not changing it. Here is a modified version that compiles and works:

```
fn mean(arr: &[f64]) -> f64 {
    let mut i = 0.0;
    let mut mean = 0.0;
    for &num in arr {
        i += 1.0;
        mean += (num - mean) / i;
    }
    mean
}
```

We specify `&num` when looping over `arr`, so that the type of `num` is `f64` rather than a reference to `f64`. This snippet would work with both, but omitting it would break the generic version.

For the same function to accept floats and integers alike, its parameter needs to be *generic*. Ideally we'd like it to accept any type that can be converted into `f64`, including `f32` or user-defined types that defin such a conversion. Something like this:

```
fn mean<T>(arr: &[T]) -> f64 {
    let mut i = 0.0;
    let mut mean = 0.0;
    for &num in arr {
        i += 1.0;
        mean += (num as f64 - mean) / i;
    }
    mean
}
```

This doesn't compile because `x as f64` is not defined for `x` of an arbitry type. Instead, we need a trait bound on `T` that defines a way to convert `T` values to `f64`. This is exactly the purpose of the [`Into` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/core/convert/trait.Into.html); every type `T` that implements `Into<U>` defines an `into(self) -> U` method. Specifying `T: Into<f64>` as the trait bound gives us the `into()` method that returns an `f64`.

We also need to request `T` to be `Copy`, to prevent reading the value from the array to "consume" the value, i.e. attempt moving it out of the array. Since primitive numbers such as integers implement `Copy`, this is ok for us. Working code then looks like this:

```
fn mean<T: Into<f64> + Copy>(arr: &[T]) -> f64 {
    let mut i = 0.0;
    let mut mean = 0.0;
    for &num in arr {
        i += 1.0;
        mean += (num.into() - mean) / i;
    }
    mean
}

fn main() {
    let val1 = mean(&vec![4.0, 5.0, 3.0, 2.0]);
    let val2 = mean(&vec![4, 5, 3, 2]);
    println!("The means are {} and {}", val1, val2);
}
```

Note that this will only work for types that define *lossless* conversion to `f64`. Thus it will work for `u32`, `i32` (as in the above example) and smaller integer types, but it won't accept for example a vector of `i64` or `u64`, which cannot be losslessly converted to `f64`.

Also note that this problem lends nicely to functional programming idioms such as [`enumerate()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.enumerate) and [`fold()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.enumerate). Although outside the scope of this already longish answer, writing out such an implementation is an exercise [hard to resist](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a098f0555e455053c47efb5f3d88fb40).

Comment: Note: in this example, I assume that `val2` uses a `Vec<i32>`, and `i32` has a lossless conversion to `f64` thus `Into<f64>` is implemented; however I don't think it would work for `i64`.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Such behavior sounds like a reasonable default, although it might not be what the user expects. I've now mentioned it in the answer explicitly.

Comment: It is reasonable, I just prefer "full disclosures". Nice answer :)